# Does craft beer have more nutritional values than regular beer?

Tags: craft-beers, nutrition

I was wondering if the craft beer has more nutritional values (vitamins and so on) than regular and cheap beer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I guess it depends on what you're deeming nutritional ***value***. Beer has 4 main ingredients:

1. Water
2. Grain
3. Yeast
4. Hops

The biggest mineral difference is going to come from the water source of the brewery. Following the exact same formula recipe/mashing instructions/yeast used/fermentation conditions (temperature, altitude, fermentation vessel)/time/etcetera... you can get very different flavor beers if the water source is different.

The next varying source of minerals would probably be in yeast. Unfortunately, I can only find [evidence of all brewing yeast lumped together](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/custom/1323569/2) at the moment.

The interesting part in craft brewing, especially at the homebrew-mad-science level, becomes all of the additives that can be placed into beer. I once met a brewer that [dry-hopped](https://byo.com/hops/item/569-dry-hopping-techniques) smoked salmon bones (right they aren't hops but the same technique) in their secondary fermentation (or clarifying stage) chamber!

These examples would be more "here is a random thing" that I found rather than being able to give you a definite answer as to "more nutrition" being provided than big-beer manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the craft beer. Regular cheap beer is not a good comparison as you don't typically get the same style of beer. Craft rules are not the same everywhere.  Typical rules is water, hop, barley, and yeast.  A non craft can use other ingredients but that same 4 is going to be the bulk.  A craft tends to be denser so in the case it would have more nutrients.